# Programa Vetor-Colunas

Tags: c++, dev-c++

Estou tentando fazer este programa ler as 4 primeiras colunas e calcular a nota final e a média, mas não consigo botar a solução correta na média aritmética.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    int i,j, M[5][5], maior;
    float mediafinais=0;
    for(i=0;i<2;i++){
        printf("\n\nNumero da Matricula [%d] : ",i      );
        scanf("%d", &M[i][0]);
        
        printf("Nota Av1: ");
        scanf("%d", &M[i][1]);
        
        printf("Nota Av2: ");
        scanf("%d", &M[i][2]);
                          
        printf("Media dos trabalhos : ");
        scanf("%d", &M[i][3]);                    
        
        printf("Nota Final: %d", M[i][1] + M[i][2] + M[i][3]);        
    }
    
    maior=M[0][3];
    int al=0;
    for(i=0;i<2;i++){       
        if(maior<M[i][3]){
            maior=M[i][3];
            al=i;
        }    
    }
    
    printf("\n A Maior Nota Final e do aluno com a matricula :");
    printf(" %d \n\n",M[al][0]);
    printf("\n\nMedia aritmetica das notas finais: %.2f ", mediafinais);
}
```

Comment: ta tendo algum erro de compilação? execução? qual seu problema??

Answer (score 0):

Olá , acredito que a pergunta foi bem genérica , acredito que você queria colocar as notas em colunas , para isso não vi uso no J . Aqui está minha visão do seu código :

```
#include <stdio.h> 

int main(){ 
    // Ja que é uma matriz de notas , é melhor criar a matriz como float
    // 2 Linhas para 2 Alunos e 5 Colunas para 5 coisas ( Matricula + av1 + av2 + trabalho + Nota Final)
    int i,qntd = 0; float mediafinais = 0, notasFinais = 0, M[2][5]; 

    for(i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        printf("\n\nNumero da Matricula [%d] : ",i);
        scanf("%f", &M[i][0]);
     
        printf("Nota Av1: ");
        scanf("%f", &M[i][1]);
        
        printf("Nota Av2: ");
        scanf("%f", &M[i][2]);
                          
        printf("Media dos trabalhos : ");
        scanf("%f", &M[i][3]);  
        
        // Coluna 4 Responsável por salvar as Notas Finais
         M[i][4]= M[i][1] + M[i][2] + M[i][3];

        // Média aritmetica no final
        notasFinais += M[i][1] + M[i][2] + M[i][3];
        qntd+=1;

        printf("Nota Final: %.2f" , M[i][4]);  
    }

    int al = 0, maior = 0, aux = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < 2; i++){
        // Estabeleço uma base para comparar os valores
        if (aux==0){
            maior = M[i][4];aux++;
        }
        else if(M[i][4] > maior){
            maior=M[i][4];
            al=i;
        }
    }

    printf("\n A Maior Nota Final e do aluno com a matricula :");
    printf(" %.0f \n\n", M[al][0]);
    // Coloquei a variavel qtd , pois você não sabe se sempre serão 2 alunos
    // Eu mantive 2 no for, pois é seu código .
    printf("\n\nMedia aritmetica das notas finais: %.2f", notasFinais/qntd);
    printf("\n\n\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Nossa obrgd msm cara ksks to acordado até agr encabulado com isso, vlw msm irmao